# How to expose native code to javascript in webkit2gtk

Tags: javascript, c, gtk3, webkit2, webkit2-webextension

I want to expose a native object or function to javascript so that i can have a callback function in C when the particular function is called in browser.

From [this](https://github.com/vrruiz/WebKit-JavaScriptCore-Extensions) example, it seems it is possible in WebKitGTK1 using the signal "**window-object-cleared**".

How can i achieve the same in WebKitGTK2, i hope it has something to do with **WebKitWebExtension**. But i am not sure and also there is not clear guidelines or examples for implementing WebKitWebExtension. Can anyone help me with a solution for my request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WebKitWebExtension is the way to do this. Currently the best documentation on how to write one of those, is [this blog post](https://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2013/09/10/webkit2gtk-web-process-extensions/). There is a `window-object-cleared` signal similar to WebKit1 that you can connect to in your web extension and there use the [JavaScriptCore API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) to define Javascript functions that are visible to your web page.